# Filtering dropdown list in Google Sheets based on a checkbox on another sheet

Tags: validation, google-sheets, filter, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

this seems like a very simple thing to do, but I've not been able to find an answer (probably because I'm not using the right words to search).

What I'm trying to do is create a dropdown list that only includes names if certain criteria are met.

I have a registration list of names on Sheet 1 Column C, with a checkbox in Sheet 1 Column E that needs to be checked once ID has been validated. On Sheet 2, I want to create a dropdown list in column C that only includes names from Sheet 1 Column C IF the Sheet 1 Column D checkbox is checked.

[Sheet 1 with Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdLgl.png)

[image: Sheet 1 with Checkbox]

[Sheet 2 with dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ch0.png)

[image: Sheet 2 with dropdown]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXLE1KfVXluFrqKavw67yeBD1vj6Sw2-p5Gp7k1wJw0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use helper column to create items for dropdown validation. in Z1 of Sheet2 paste:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!C:C; Sheet1!E:E=TRUE)
```

then create dropdown from list of items located in Z column. when you done you can hide Z column and forget it.